# delete column is not working properly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to delete column on click event now the problem is when I click on number 2 it deletes the second column its fine now then I click on number 3 it deletes number 3 but not its column code is

what is wrong here can anyone help me to figure it out.

```js
$(document).on('click',".button", function( event){
 var attrNumColumn = $(this).attr('attrnum');
  $(".button[attrnum='"+attrNumColumn+"']").remove();
  //console.log($(this).attr('attrnum'));
  var attrNumColumnMinus = parseInt($(this).attr('attrnum')-1);
  $('tr').each(function(){
   $(this).children("td:eq("+attrNumColumnMinus+")").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #c30202;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" attrnum='1'> 1 </div>
<div class="button" attrnum='2'> 2 </div>
<div class="button" attrnum='3'> 3 </div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: If you remove column 2 you only have 2 columns - so when you click on '3', it tries to remove column 3, but there is no column 3 as you already removed column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function was not working since you assume the length of tr always same irrespective of node removal, so when u remove the second element the length of the `td in tr's` will become 2 and on the removal `attrnum='3'` it'll try to access 3-1 td[2] which is not present. I've updated your code, please take a look.

```js
$(document).on('click',".button", function( event){
 var attrNumColumn = $(this).attr('attrnum');
  $(".button[attrnum='"+attrNumColumn+"']").remove();
  //console.log($(this).attr('attrnum'));
  $('tr').each(function(){
   $(this).children("td[attrnum='"+attrNumColumn+"']").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #c30202;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button" attrnum='1'> 1 </div>
<div class="button" attrnum='2'> 2 </div>
<div class="button" attrnum='3'> 3 </div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td attrnum='1'>1</td>
    <td attrnum='2'>2</td>
    <td attrnum='3'>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td attrnum='1'>4</td>
    <td attrnum='2'>5</td>
    <td attrnum='3'>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td attrnum='1'>7</td>
    <td attrnum='2'>8</td>
    <td attrnum='3'>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `$(".button").index(this)` to get the index of the button, and then use that number to remove the correct `td`.

I've also shortened your code.

```
$(document).on('click',".button", function( event){
    var number = $(".button").index(this)
    $(this).add("tr td:nth-child(" + (number + 1) + ")").remove() // credit to Endless for this line
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', ".button", function(event) {
  var number = $(".button").index(this)
  $(this).add("tr td:nth-child(" + (number + 1) + ")").remove()
});
```

```css
.button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 10px;
}

.button:hover {
  color: #c30202;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button" attrnum='1'> 1 </div>
<div class="button" attrnum='2'> 2 </div>
<div class="button" attrnum='3'> 3 </div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Suggestion: `$(this).add("tr td:nth-child(" + (number + 1) + ")").remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Try below javascript code:

```
    <div class="button" attrnum='1'> 1 </div>
<div class="button" attrnum='2'> 2 </div>
<div class="button" attrnum='3'> 3 </div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-1">1</td>
    <td class="col-2">2</td>
    <td class="col-3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-1">4</td>
    <td class="col-2">5</td>
    <td class="col-3">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-1">7</td>
    <td class="col-2">8</td>
    <td class="col-3">9</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$(document).on('click',".button", function( event){
    var attrNumColumn = $(this).attr('attrnum');
  $('.col-'+attrNumColumn).remove();  
});
```

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/9p77afc3/10/

If you want to delete number also than try: https://jsfiddle.net/9p77afc3/11/

Comment: You code is not working. Try hit number 2, then hit number 3

Comment: Now, Its working. Please check above code. @CarstenLøvboAndersen